# How to enable InteliSense for Phalcon in VS Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, windows-10, phalcon

I'm using XAMPP with PHP 7.3 with Phalcon 3.4 extension in Windows 10.
I've been having issues on getting code suggestion, or even errors because VS Code can't seem to find Phalcon files.

I've been seeing PhpStorm tutorials and then just including Phalcon Dev Tool in the include path.

Extra Notes: I am using Inteliphense, but I'm willing to use Intelisense from Felix Becker

Do VS Code have this? How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also install the following package or VSCode :
`composer require phalcon/ide-stubs --dev`

Comment: Yes, this answer really works. I have a fresh Phalcon PHP installation and a new project. In this case I created a very basic `composer.json` file, then `composer update` to download the basic packages and after that `composer require phalcon/ide-stubs --dev`. Last but not least restart the VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP IntelliSense from Felix Becker - you need to add all the Phalcon Stubs to language server stubs cache inside felixbecker/intellisense plugin. Or, you can use your own language server, but it not easy way to have autocompletion into VSCode...

Comment: The PHP Intelephense from Ben Mewburn is much superior. Recommended.